# Making choropleth maps using PostGIS and Windows

Tags: postgis, google-maps, mapnik, tilemill, choropleth

I read an article on Chicago tribune blog about [making maps](http://blog.apps.chicagotribune.com/2011/03/08/making-maps-1/).  It mentions "making choropleth maps using PostGIS, TileMill, Mapnik and Google Maps" on Mac environment.

How can we make the same thing on the Windows environment?

I want to make a Side-by-side map comparisons like [this](http://media.apps.chicagotribune.com/ward-redistricting/index.html#41.74813465976077,-87.62609481811523,12,0)

Comment: All those tools run on Windows too. Have you actually tried it?

Answer (score 1):

there are lots of tools making Thematic Map on the net. but if you search free gis tools for making colorful maps, i advice you to read following link for getting some information about it.

[How to Make a US County Thematic Map Using Free Tools](http://flowingdata.com/2009/11/12/how-to-make-a-us-county-thematic-map-using-free-tools/)

Example:

[image: Thematic Map]

and another link is about mapping with python too...

[A Thematic Map in Python](http://danieljlewis.org/2010/05/25/a-thematic-map-in-python/)

Example:

[image: Thematic Map in Python]

with installing python on windows machine you can make your maps, but I recommend you at least install vmware linux machine to get rid of some dependency problem.